# PHP Delete and Re-insert all data from the form in edit.php

Tags: php, mysql, forms

I have tried to update data through edit page by deleting all of the existing data from the 'positions' table and then re-insert them. When I press the 'Save' button, the page redirects perfectly to index page, but when i view the profile I see that the 'positions' database is empty.

Plz help as I have been grinding on this problem for a week now.

**Edit.php**

```
<?php
session_start();
$pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;port=3306;dbname=misc',
   'rs', 'rs123');
// See the "errors" folder for details...
$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

if ( isset($_POST['first_name']) && isset($_POST['last_name'])
     && isset($_POST['email']) && isset($_POST['headline'])
     && isset($_POST['summary']) && isset($_POST['profile_id'])) {

    // Data validation
    if(filter_var($_POST['email'],FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)){
        if ( !isset($_POST['first_name']) || !isset($_POST['last_name'])
         || !isset($_POST['email']) || !isset($_POST['headline']) || !isset($_POST['summary'])) {
         $_SESSION['failure'] = "All fields are required";
         header("Location: edit.php?profile_id=". $_REQUEST["profile_id"]);
         return;
        }
    }
    else{    
        $_SESSION["failure"] = "Email address must have an @ sign.";
        header("Location: edit.php?profile_id=". $_REQUEST["profile_id"]);
        return;
        }
    $sql = "UPDATE `profile` SET first_name = ?,
            last_name = ?, email = ?,
            headline = ?, summary=?
            WHERE profile_id = ?";
    $stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->execute(array(
        $_POST['first_name'],
        $_POST['last_name'],
        $_POST['email'],
        $_POST['headline'],
        $_POST['summary'],
        $_POST['profile_id']));
        $profile_id = $_GET['profile_id'];
            $stmt = $pdo->prepare("DELETE FROM `Position` WHERE `profile_id` = ?");
            $stmt->execute(array($_GET['profile_id']));
            $rank=1;
            for($i=1; $i<=9; $i++) {
             if ( ! isset($_POST['year'.$i]) ) continue;
             if ( ! isset($_POST['desc'.$i]) ) continue;
             $year = $_POST['year'.$i];
             $desc = $_POST['desc'.$i];
           $stmt = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO `position`
           (`profile_id`, `rank`, `year`, `description`) 
           VALUES ( ?, ?, ?, ?)");
           $stmt->execute(array($profile_id, $rank, $year, $desc)); 
           $rank++;
            } 
          $_SESSION["success"]="Record Added";
            header("Location: index.php");
            return;
           }
         $stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT `profile_id`, `first_name`, `last_name`, `email`, `headline`, `summary` FROM `profile` WHERE `profile_id` = ?");
         $stmt->execute(array($_GET['profile_id']));
         $row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
         
         // Flash pattern
         if ( isset($_SESSION['failure']) ) {
             echo '<p style="color:red">'.$_SESSION['failure']."</p>\n";
             unset($_SESSION['failure']);
         }
         
         $fname = htmlentities($row['first_name']);
         $lname = htmlentities($row['last_name']);
         $email = htmlentities($row['email']);
         $headline = htmlentities($row['headline']);
         $summary = htmlentities($row['summary']);
         $profile_id = $row['profile_id'];
         
         
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title>Rounak Simlai</title>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-fLW2N01lMqjakBkx3l/M9EahuwpSfeNvV63J5ezn3uZzapT0u7EYsXMjQV+0En5r" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.js" integrity="sha256-DZAnKJ/6XZ9si04Hgrsxu/8s717jcIzLy3oi35EouyE=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
<h1>Editing profile for<?php echo" ".$_SESSION['name'];?></h1>
<form method="post">
  <p>First Name:
  <input type="text" name="first_name" value="<?php echo($fname); ?>" size="60"/></p>
  <p>Last Name:
  <input type="text" name="last_name" value="<?php echo($lname); ?>" size="40"/></p>
  <p>Email:
  <input type="text" name="email" value="<?php echo($email); ?>"/></p>
  <p>Headline:<br>
  <input type="text" name="headline" value="<?php echo($headline); ?>"/></p>
  <p>Summary:<br/>
  <textarea name="summary"  rows="8" cols="80"> <?php echo($summary); ?> </textarea></p>
  <input type="hidden" name="profile_id" value="<?php echo($profile_id); ?>">
  <p>Position: <input type="submit" id="addPos" value="+">
  <div id="position_fields">
  <?php 
  $stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM `position` WHERE profile_id = ?");
  $stmt->execute(array($_GET['profile_id']));
  foreach($stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) as $row){
      $year=$row['year'];
      $desc=$row['description']; 
      $countPos = 1;
      echo"<div id='position'".$countPos.">"; 
      echo"<p> Year: <input type='text' name=\"year ".$countPos."\" value='".$year."' /> ";
      echo"<input type=\"button\" value=\"-\" onclick=\"$(\'#position'+countPos+'\').remove();return false;\"></p> ";
      echo"<textarea name=\"desc".$countPos."' rows=\"8\" cols=\"80\" >$desc</textarea>";
      echo"</div>";
      $countPos++;
  }
?>
  </div>
  </p>
  <p>
  <input type="submit" id="submit" value="Save"/>
  <a href="index.php">Cancel</a></p>
</form>
</div>
<script>
countPos = 1;
$(document).ready(function(){
    window.console && console.log('Document ready called');
    $('#addPos').click(function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        if ( countPos >= 9 ) {
            alert("Maximum of nine position entries exceeded");
            return;
        }
        countPos++;
        window.console && console.log("Adding position "+countPos);
        $('#position_fields').append(
            '<div id="position'+countPos+'"> \
            <p>Year: <input type="text" name="year'+countPos+'" value="" /> \
            <input type="button" value="-" \
            onclick="$(\'#position'+countPos+'\').remove();return false;"></p> \
            <textarea name="desc'+countPos+'" rows="8" cols="80"></textarea>\
            </div>');
    });
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

**VIEW.PHP**

```
    <?php
session_start();
$pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;port=3306;dbname=misc',
   'rs', 'rs123');
// See the "errors" folder for details...
$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    $stmt= $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM profile WHERE profile_id = ?");
    $stmt->execute(array($_GET['profile_id']));
    $row=$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    $fname=htmlentities($row['first_name']);
    $lname=htmlentities($row['last_name']);
    $email=htmlentities($row['email']);
    $headline=htmlentities($row['headline']);
    $summary=htmlentities($row['summary']);
    $profile_id=htmlentities($row['profile_id']);
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Rounak Simlai</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-fLW2N01lMqjakBkx3l/M9EahuwpSfeNvV63J5ezn3uZzapT0u7EYsXMjQV+0En5r" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.js" integrity="sha256-DZAnKJ/6XZ9si04Hgrsxu/8s717jcIzLy3oi35EouyE=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
<h1>Profile information</h1>
<form method="post">
<p>First Name: <?php echo(" ".$fname); ?></p>
<p>Last Name: <?php echo(" ".$lname); ?> </p>
<p>Email: <?php echo(" ".$email); ?>    </p>
<p>Headline: <?php echo(" ".$headline); ?>  <br/></p>
<p>Summary: <?php echo(" ".$summary); ?>   <br/><p>
<input type="hidden" name="profile_id" value="<?= $profile_id ?>">
</p>
<p>Position</p><ul>
<?php
$stmt= $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM position WHERE profile_id = ?");
$stmt->execute(array($_GET['profile_id']));
foreach($stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) as $row){
    echo"<li>".$row['year']." : ".$row['description']."</li>";
}

?>
</ul>
<a href="index.php">Done</a>
</form>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

**ADD.PHP**

```
    <?php
session_start();
$pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;port=3306;dbname=misc',
   'rs', 'rs123');
// See the "errors" folder for details...
$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
function validatePos() {
  for($i=1; $i<=9; $i++) {
      if ( ! isset($_POST['year'.$i]) ) continue;
      if ( ! isset($_POST['desc'.$i]) ) continue;
      $year = $_POST['year'.$i];
      $desc = $_POST['desc'.$i];
      if ( strlen($year) == 0 || strlen($desc) == 0 ) {
          return "All fields are required";
      }

      if ( ! is_numeric($year) ) {
          return "Position year must be numeric";
      }
  }
  return true;
}
$failure=false;
$success=false;
if(isset($_POST['first_name'])&& isset($_POST['last_name'])
    && isset($_POST['email']) && isset($_POST['headline'])
    && isset($_POST['summary'])){
   
  if(strlen($_POST['first_name'])<1 || strlen($_POST['last_name'])<1
  ||strlen($_POST['email'])<1 || strlen($_POST['headline'])<1
  ||strlen($_POST['summary'])<1){  
          $_SESSION['failure'] = "All values are required";
          header("Location: add.php");
          return;
      }
 if(!filter_var($_POST['email'],FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)){
        $_SESSION["failure"]="Email address must contain @ sign.";
          header("Location: add.php");
          return;
    }   
  $stmt = $pdo->prepare('INSERT INTO `profile`(`user_id`, first_name, last_name, email, headline, summary) 
                         VALUES ( ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)');
$stmt->execute(array($_SESSION['user_id'], 
                     $_POST['first_name'], 
                     $_POST['last_name'], 
                     $_POST['email'], 
                     $_POST['headline'], 
                     $_POST['summary']));
         $profile_id = $pdo->lastInsertId();
         if($stmt==true){
           $rank=1;
          for($i=1; $i<=9; $i++) {
            if ( ! isset($_POST['year'.$i]) ) continue;
            if ( ! isset($_POST['desc'.$i]) ) continue;
            $year = $_POST['year'.$i];
            $desc = $_POST['desc'.$i];
            
          $stmt = $pdo->prepare('INSERT INTO Position
          (profile_id, `rank`, `year`, `description`) 
          VALUES ( ?, ?, ?, ?)');
          $stmt->execute(array($profile_id, $rank, $year, $desc));
          $rank++;
        } 
         $_SESSION["success"]="Record Added";
           header("Location: index.php");
           return;
          }

}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Rounak Simlai</title>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">
<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-fLW2N01lMqjakBkx3l/M9EahuwpSfeNvV63J5ezn3uZzapT0u7EYsXMjQV+0En5r" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.js" integrity="sha256-DZAnKJ/6XZ9si04Hgrsxu/8s717jcIzLy3oi35EouyE=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="container">
  <h1>Adding profile for<?php echo" ".$_SESSION['name']; ?></h1>
  <form method="post">
  <?php
  if ( isset($_SESSION["failure"]) ) {
      echo('<p style="color: red;">'.htmlentities($_SESSION["failure"])."</p>\n");
      unset($_SESSION["failure"]);
  }
  ?>
  <p>First Name:
  <input type="text" name="first_name" size="60"/></p>
  <p>Last Name:
  <input type="text" name="last_name" size="40"/></p>
  <p>Email:
  <input type="text" name="email"/></p>
  <p>Headline:<br>
  <input type="text" name="headline"/></p>
  <p>Summary:<br/>
  <textarea name="summary" rows="8" cols="80"></textarea></p>
  <p>
  Position: <input type="submit" id="addPos" value="+">
  <div id="position_fields">
  </div>
  </p>
  <input type="submit" value="Add">
  <a href="index.php"> Cancel </a>
  </form>
</div>
<script>

countPos = 0;
$(document).ready(function(){
    window.console && console.log('Document ready called');
    $('#addPos').click(function(event){
     event.preventDefault();
        if ( countPos >= 9 ) {
            alert("Maximum of nine position entries exceeded");
            return;
        }
        countPos++;
        window.console && console.log("Adding position "+countPos);
        $('#position_fields').append(
            '<div id="position'+countPos+'"> \
            <p>Year: <input type="text" name="year'+countPos+'" value="" /> \
            <input type="button" value="-" \
                onclick="$(\'#position'+countPos+'\').remove();return false;"></p> \
            <textarea name="desc'+countPos+'" rows="8" cols="80"></textarea>\
            </div>');
    });
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

**INDEX.PHP**

```
    <?php
session_start();
$pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;port=3306;dbname=misc',
   'rs', 'rs123');
// See the "errors" folder for details...
$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
?>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Rounak Simlai</title>

  <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">

  <!-- Optional theme -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-fLW2N01lMqjakBkx3l/M9EahuwpSfeNvV63J5ezn3uZzapT0u7EYsXMjQV+0En5r" crossorigin="anonymous">

</head>
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <h1>Rounak Simlai's Resume Registry</h1>
    
<?php
  if (!isset($_COOKIE['data']))
  {
    echo '<p><a href="login.php">Please log in</a></p>';
    echo('<table border="1">'."\n"); 
        $stmt= $pdo->prepare("SELECT profile_id, first_name, last_name, headline FROM `profile`");
        $stmt->execute();
        if($stmt->rowCount()==0){
          echo "No Rows Found";
        }
        else{
     echo"<thead><tr>
          <th>Name</th>
          <th>Headline</th>
          </tr></thead>";
        while($row=$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
            echo "<tr><td>";
            echo'<a href="view.php?profile_id='.$row['profile_id'].'">'.htmlentities($row['first_name']).' '.htmlentities($row['last_name']).'</a>';
            echo("</td><td>");
            echo(htmlentities($row['headline']));
            echo("</td><td>");
        
          }
        }
      }    
  if (isset($_COOKIE['data'])){
        $msg=false;
        if(isset($_SESSION["success"])) {
         echo('<p style="color: green;">'.htmlentities($_SESSION["success"])."</p>\n");
         unset($_SESSION['success']);
    }
    echo('<table border="1">'."\n"); 
    $stmt= $pdo->prepare("SELECT profile_id, first_name, last_name, headline FROM `profile`");
    $stmt->execute();
    if($stmt->rowCount()==0){
      $msg="No Rows Found";
    }
    else{
 echo"<thead><tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Headline</th>
      <th>Action</th>
      </tr></thead>";
    while($row=$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
        echo "<tr><td>";
        echo'<a href="view.php?profile_id='.$row['profile_id'].'">'.htmlentities($row['first_name']).' '.htmlentities($row['last_name']).'</a>';
        echo("</td><td>");
        echo(htmlentities($row['headline']));
        echo("</td><td>");
        echo('<a href="edit.php?profile_id='.$row['profile_id'].'">Edit</a> / ');
        echo('<a href="delete.php?profile_id='.$row['profile_id'].'">Delete</a>');
        echo("</td></tr>\n");  
          }
        }
          echo"<p>".htmlentities($msg)."</p>
          <p><a href=\"add.php\">Add New Entry</a></p>
          <p><a href=\"logout.php\">Logout</a></p>
          </div>";
        }
?>
</body>
</html>
```

**DELETE.PHP**

```
    <?php
session_start();
$pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;port=3306;dbname=misc',
   'rs', 'rs123');
// See the "errors" folder for details...
$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

if ( isset($_POST['delete']) && isset($_POST['profile_id']) ) {
    $sql = "DELETE FROM `profile` WHERE profile_id = ?";
    $stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->execute(array($_POST['profile_id']));
    $_SESSION['success'] = 'Record deleted';
    header( 'Location: index.php' ) ;
    return;
}

$stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT first_name, last_name, profile_id FROM `profile` where profile_id = ?");
$stmt->execute(array($_GET['profile_id']));
$row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<title>Rounak Simlai</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-fLW2N01lMqjakBkx3l/M9EahuwpSfeNvV63J5ezn3uZzapT0u7EYsXMjQV+0En5r" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
<h1>Deleting profile</h1>
<form method="post">
<p>First Name: <?php echo($row['first_name']); ?> </p>
<p>Last Name: <?php echo($row['last_name']);?> </p>
<input type="hidden" name="profile_id" value="<?= $row['profile_id'] ?>">
<input type="submit" value="Delete" name="delete">
<a href="index.php">Cancel</a>
</form>
</div>    
</body>
</html>
```

**LOGIN.PHP**

```
    <?php // Do not put any HTML above this line
session_start();
$pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;port=3306;dbname=misc',
   'rs', 'rs123');
// See the "errors" folder for details...
$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

$salt = 'XyZzy12*_';
$failure = false;  // If we have no POST data
// Check to see if we have some POST data, if we do process it
if ( isset($_POST['email']) && isset($_POST['pass']) ) {
    if(filter_var($_POST['email'],FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)){
    if ( strlen($_POST['email']) < 1 || strlen($_POST['pass']) < 1 ) {
      $_SESSION["failure"] = "Email and password are required";
      header("Location: login.php");
      return;
      } else {
          $check = hash('md5', $salt.$_POST['pass']);
          $stmt = $pdo->prepare('SELECT `user_id`, `name` FROM users WHERE email = ? AND pass = ?');
          $stmt->execute(array($_POST['email'], $check));
          $row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);        
          if ( $row !== false ) {
            $_SESSION['name'] = $row['name'];
            $_SESSION['user_id'] = $row['user_id'];
            setcookie('data','1999');            
            // Redirect the browser to index.php
            header("Location: index.php");
            return;
        } else {
            $_SESSION["failure"] = "Incorrect password";
            error_log("Login fail ".$_POST['email']." $check");
            header("Location: login.php");
            return;
        }
    }
 }
 else{
   $_SESSION["failure"] = "Email must have an @ sign.";
   header("Location: login.php");
   return;

  }
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Rounak Simlai</title>
</head>
<body>
<?php require_once "bootstrap.php"; ?>
<div class="container">
<h1>Please Log In</h1>
<?php
if ( isset($_SESSION["failure"]) ) {
    echo('<p style="color: red;">'.htmlentities($_SESSION["failure"])."</p>\n");
    unset($_SESSION["failure"]);
}
?>
<form method="POST">
<label for="nam">User Name</label>
<input type="text" name="email" id="email"><br/>
<label for="id_1723">Password</label>
<input type="text" name="pass" id="id_1723"><br/>
<input type="submit" onclick="return doValidate();" value="Log In">
<a href="index.php">Cancel</a>
</form>
<p><br>
For a password hint, view source and find a password hint
in the HTML comments.
<!-- Hint: The password is the three character name of the
programming language used in this class (all lower case)
followed by 123. -->
</p>
</div>

<script>
function doValidate() {
    console.log('Validating...');
    try {
        addr = document.getElementById('email').value;
        pw = document.getElementById('id_1723').value;
        console.log("Validating addr="+addr+" pw="+pw);
        if (addr == null || addr == "" || pw == null || pw == "") {
            alert("Both fields must be filled out");
            return false;
        }
        if ( addr.indexOf('@') == -1 ) {
            alert("Invalid email address");
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    } catch(e) {
        return false;
    }
    return false;
}</script>

</body>
</html>
```

**LOGOUT.PHP**

```
    <?php
    session_start();
    setcookie('data');
    unset($_SESSION['name']);
    unset($_SESSION['user_id']);
    header("Location: index.php");
    
    
?>
```